# How to make Flake8 ignore syntax within strings?

Tags: python, pre-commit, flake8

I'm suddenly getting flake8 errors for syntax within strings.

For example, for the following line of code:

```
    tags.append(f'error_type:{error.get("name")}')
```

I'm getting this error: `E231 missing whitespace after ':'`.

I don't want to ignore all `E231` errors, because I care about them when they don't refer to text within strings.

I also don't want to have to go and add `# noqa` comments to each of my strings.

I've tried to pin my flake8 version to `6.0.0` (which is the version that previously didn't raise these errors before).

I'm running flake8 with pre-commit (if that is relevant).

Why am I suddenly getting these errors for strings and how can I turn them off?

I should also mention that this is happening in Github Actions, specifically.

Comment: This definitely sounds like a bug in flake8.

Comment: this is definitely a bug that I fixed months ago :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This issue seems limited to Python 3.12+ and it was fixed by flake8 version 6.1.0.

The errors stopped appearing when I upgrade to flake8 6.1.0.